# Can I get some strategy to unstack column into key value pairs, with a view to make a logical table

Tags: excel, powerquery

I import a data set that comes in a list form,

The list has lots of annoying features that I just keep hitting walls when trying to organise and sort into a logical table. Previously I have used a mix of power Query and Macros to "Automate" the organisation but Id like to eliminate the macros I use, tbh when it comes to power query I have basic skills but can follow documentation for syntax etc..

A Simple example is as follows:

| Column A |
| --- |
| Name |
| A smith |
| Age |
| 31 |
| Birthday |
| 30th |
| BirthMonth |
| Feb |
| Name |
| B Heinz |
| Age |
| Birthda |
| 15th |
| BirthMonth |
| Name |
| C Chaplin |
| Age |
| Birthday |
| 4th |
| BirthMonth |
| Jan |

Note the name-value pairs are stacked on top of one another but do not iterate in equal intervals, all of the 'names' are repeated equally but if a value is not recored then the next row contains the next name  and etc,etc...

I already tried *(paraphrasing the syntax here:)*

=(list.split(Table1[ColumnA],6))

Note i was trying to create something like :

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | B Heinz | Age |  | Birthday |
| name | C Chaplin | Age |  | Birthday |

(And obviously the rest of the data organised into this same column of names colum of value or not)

In my mind reaching this point with the data would be easier for me to figure out my end goal...

But as stated its not an equal iteration so the name values end up distributed throughout different columns... so then I have a new puzzle but instead of a list, Ill have a jumbled table.

In the end I would like to get the names as the column headers and the values in the corresponding column

So what im asking is any advice or methods that might be of interest,
The actual list conains a lot of data so im interested in stretegy or methods to approach this ?

There will be a daily list added to the data set so im keen to not use the macros any more...

Apologies for any spelling / formatting errors, this is my 1st post and Im winging the use of power query to achieve my goal

Comment: I don't see an age for Heinz or Chaplin, how are you getting 23 and 32 from your sample data

Comment: @horseyride apolgies, an oversight, there would not be a value for age for either name.

Comment: How do you know when a row gets omitted? Are there literally key words like name and birthday that are used in rows before the rows containing the actual name and actual birthday ? What is the list of keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You will need to have a list of the pivoted Column Headers someplace.
- I have also assumed that

  - each set of entries has a **Name**
  - **Name** is the first item in the group of entries

If that is the case, the following code should work.
 Please read the code comments and explore the applied steps to better understand the alogrithm.

```
let

//List of Column Headers can be in an Excel table
// or you could hard code it here
#"Headers List" = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Headers"]}[Content],
    Headers = List.Buffer(Table.Column(#"Headers List","Column1")),
        
//Change next lines to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table29"]}[Content],

//add a custom column with just the proposed column headers
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type any}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Headers", each if List.Contains(Headers,[Column1]) then [Column1] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Headers"}),

//Remove rows with headers only (headers in both column1 and header column
    #"Remove Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each not List.Contains(Headers,[Column1])),

//Add Column with just Name header, for grouping
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Remove Rows", "Grouper", each if [Headers]="Name" then [Column1] else null, type text),
    #"Filled Down1" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom1",{"Grouper"}),

//Group by Name
//  Then Pivot each subtable with no aggregation
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down1", {"Grouper"}, {
        {"Pivot", (t)=>Table.Pivot(t, List.Distinct(t[Headers]), "Headers", "Column1"),
            type table[Name=text, Age=Int64.Type, Birthday=text, BirthMonth=text]}
        }),

//Remove uneeded columns and expand the Pivoted tables
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Grouper"}),
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Pivot", {"Name", "Age", "Birthday", "BirthMonth"})
in
    #"Expanded Pivot"
```

***Headers***
[image]

***Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]